# In Android get center of Relative Layout on API 10

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to find the center coordinates of a `RelativeLayout` that for the moment, is empty. I need to find the center before I can put anything into the Relative Layout. The Relative Layout is not the whole screen, so I can't use metrics to find the screen dimensions. Since my minimum API is 10, I can't use `rLayout.getX()` or `rLayout.getY()`. So what I've tried is:

```
int xScreenInt = gBoard_RL.getWidth()/2;
int yScreenInt = gBoard_RL.getHeight()/2;

int xInt = gBoard_RL.getLeft() + xScreenInt;
int yInt = gBoard_RL.getTop() + yScreenInt;
```

and all I get is 0,0. Does anyone have an any ideas how I can get this done? Here's my layout and the Activity so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/gb1_root_RL"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
tools:context=".GB1" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/gb1_topInfo_RL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/blu_grade_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gb1_scValue_TV"
        style="@style/mainScoreValueStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gb1_score_TV"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gb1_timeValue_TV"
        style="@style/mainTimeValueStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gb1_time_TV"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/gb1_gf_RL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gb1_topInfo_RL"
    android:padding="10dp" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

the Relative Layout I need to find the center of is: `android:id="@+id/gb1_gf_RL"`

```
public class GB1 extends Activity {
TextView GScore_TV;

RelativeLayout gBoard_RL;
int xScreenInt, yScreenInt, xInt, yInt;
String xStr, yStr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.cutin, R.anim.cutout);
    setContentView(R.layout.gb_layout);
    GScore_TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.G1_scoreValue_TV);
    gBoard_RL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gb1_gf_RL);


    gBoard_RL.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);

    xScreenInt = gBoard_RL.getWidth()/2;
    yScreenInt = gBoard_RL.getHeight()/2;

    xInt = gBoard_RL.getLeft() + xScreenInt;
    yInt = gBoard_RL.getTop() + yScreenInt;

    xStr = String.valueOf(xInt);
    yStr = String.valueOf(yInt);
    GScore_TV.setText(xStr + ", " + yStr);
}

}
```

Comment: there is a nice trick for getting the center of a relative layout. an empty view set to `centerInParent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your code in a `onGlobalLayout` listener:

```
myRelativelayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        this.layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        //Your code here
     }
});
```

**EDIT:**
Since, as @xorgate pointed out, the layout isnt drawn yet in the onCreate method. The `onGlobalLayout` method will be called when the layout is drawn and calculations such as yours should be done in there.

Comment: I got it to work using `public void getGBsize(){
  gBoard_RL.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    oGLL); 
 }
 
 
 OnGlobalLayoutListener oGLL = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
  @Override
  public void onGlobalLayout() {
   
   int xScreenInt = gBoard_RL.getWidth()/2;
   int yScreenInt = gBoard_RL.getHeight()/2;
   int xInt = gBoard_RL.getLeft() + xScreenInt;
   int yInt = gBoard_RL.getTop() + yScreenInt;
   
   xStr = String.valueOf(xInt);
   yStr = String.valueOf(yInt);
   
   GScore_TV.setText(xStr + ", " + yStr);
  }
 };`

Answer (score 0):

onCreate is called before a layout pass is done. All Views will have no size yet.

Try setting a global layout listener, and do the positioning code there.